# Exclude subfolder in WordPress permalink

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have built a test website with this permalink structure: https://www.test.de.www279.your-server.de/

Now I exported it to a live domain with all in one wp migrate and urls got changed aligned to the live domain (test2.de)

Sadly, in many image URLs etc there still is the subfolder [www.279.your-server.de](http://www.279.your-server.de) implemented which is causing a lot of errors.

Search and Replace did not work at all. Any way I can debug this?

**What I want**

Change all
https://www.test.de.www279.your-server.de/

to

https://www.test.de

and make sure that images like https://www.test.de.www279.your-server.de//wp-content/uploads/2021/11/testg.jpg automatically skip the www.279 part.

Bests,

Comment: You might try Migrate DB pro. They have a DB search and replace feature that works pretty well: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/

Comment: I tried several plugins of those types... None work unfortunately. Was looking for a code or something else.